# How to test this function which uses get_template without providing a template path?

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking

I've got this function:

```
def _render(object, template, context_name=None, classes=None):
"""
Helper function that execute the form/field actual rendering.

"""
if not context_name:
    context_name = 'object'
template = get_template(template)
c = {
    context_name: object,
    'classes': classes,
}
return template.render(Context(c))
```

I want to test it, but I don't want to provide any existing template in my file system just a "virtual" one like ie. `input_chunk`:

```
class RenderCustomChunk(TestCase):
"""
The ``_render()`` class should return a fully rendered html code
based on the given template chunk and parameters passed
with the rendering function ie. classes.

"""
def setUp(self):
    self.test_object = 'Test Object'
    self.test_template_name = 'TestTemplate.html'

    self.input_chunk = u'<p>{{ object }}</p>'
    self.render_output = u'<p>%s</p>' % self.test_object

def test_should_render_custom_object(self):
    self.assertEqual(forms._render(self.test_object, self.test_template_name),
                     self.render_output)
```

Is there any elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't think you are trying to test the get_template function (you're using a "virtual" file after all, which is not what get_template is for), another solution is to mock get_template.

```
# tests.py
from foo import forms

def mock_get_template():
    return django.template.Template(u'<p>{{ object }}</p>')

forms.get_template = mock_get_template
```

or inline if it looks cleaner in the setUp()

```
class RenderCustomChunk(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_object = 'Test Object'
        self.test_template_name = 'TestTemplate.html'

        self.render_output = u'<p>%s</p>' % self.test_object

        # this is a unit test for _render, not get_template.
        forms.get_template = lambda x: Template(u'<p>{{ object }}</p>')

    def test_should_render_custom_object(self):
        self.assertEqual(forms._render(self.test_object, self.test_template_name),
                         self.render_output)
```

Comment: that will just push the responsibility and still I won't be able to test function usage with template path instead of template instance, so "no go" for this solution. I thought about many solution including stripping get_template off this helper. But I'm looking for an elegant, maybe mock-related one - that's why I've posted a question - I'm not looking for easy stuff here ;)

Comment: Roger that. So you want to test the function with a template path. Does that mean you want to test get_template functionality or just _render? get_template uses file = open(path) at its core, so I think using a "virtual" file is impossible. You'd have to mock some point in the function to return your virtual file contents instead the real open(). A cleaner solution w/o modifying the _render function could be to mock the get_template function in your test. What do you think? updating with example :)

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? If you're not the testing get_template function itself (whether it successfully retrieves a file via template loaders), then mocking the get_template function should solve your problem.